# Subset of the full shift is compact and transititve

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let Consider the set $\Sigma = \{0,1,2,,,n-1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ consisting of all two-sided sequence of elements in $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$.

Define the full shift map $T:\Sigma \to \Sigma$ by $\sigma(...,x_{-1}\,x_o\,x_1\,x_2\,,...) = (...,x_1\,x_2\,,...)$, which is homeomorphim.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ binary matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$ for $i,j\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, in which case

$$\Sigma_A\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z\rangle\in\Sigma_n:a_{x_k,x_{k+1}}=1\text{ for each }k\in\Bbb Z\}\,.$$

In other words, $\Sigma_A$ consists of the sequences in $\Sigma_n$ that are walks along with the graph with vertex set $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and adjacency matrix $A$. The map $T:\Sigma_{A} \to \Sigma_{A}$ is a subshift of finite type.

Let $T:\Sigma \to \Sigma$ be a two side full shift on the compact metric space $\Sigma$, and let a subshift $\Sigma' \subset \Sigma$ with $\mu(\Sigma')>0$ for some some $T-$invariant measure $\mu$. The Poincaré recurrence theorem says for almost every $x\in \Sigma'$ there exists $r(x)\ge 1$ such that $T^{r(x)}(x) \in \Sigma'$.
One can take $r(x)$ smallest, of course.
The first-return map is $g(x)=T^{r(x)}(x)$. So, the return map is defined on a full measure subset  of the measurable set $\Sigma'$. Is $\Sigma^{'}$  closed?

Assume that every element of $\Sigma'$ is dense i.e for every element $x\in \Sigma$, there is $x_{n} \in \Sigma'$ such that $x_{n} \to x$. Is that true that $T_{|\Sigma^{'}}$ transitive?

My answer:[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837914/closedness-of-subshift) showed that the subshifts of finite type are compact.

Regarding transitivity, since the full shift is transitive, there is a point $p$, which has a dense orbit. On the other hand, every element of $\Sigma'$ is dense, so there is $(x_{n}) \in \Sigma'$ such that $x_{n} \to p$. Then, the result follows from the continuity.

Comment: First, the question lacks definitions. What are full shift, $T_{|\Sigma^{'}}$, and dense *elements*? Next, a subset $\Sigma’$ of a compact metric space $\Sigma$ is compact iff $\Sigma’$ is closed in $\Sigma$. So I guess that if $x$ is a non-isolated point of $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma’=\Sigma\setminus\{x\}$ then $\mu(\Sigma’)>0$ but $\Sigma’$ is not compact.

Comment: @AlexRavsky : I added all definitions.

Comment: @AlexRavsky already replied to your first question (think that the measure is not atomic). As for the second, he already noted that you need to define "dense element". What do subshifts of finite type have to do with the question?

Comment: Somehow I feel like there is a missing hypothesis on $\Sigma'$. As currently stated, the only hypothesis on $\Sigma'$ is that it is a subset of $\Sigma$ that has a positive measure with respect to some $T$-invariant measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$. Well, there's plenty of noncompact subsets of $\Sigma$ of that form.

Comment: @JohnB I updated the question. Regarding your question, I thought $\Sigma'$ is a subshift.

Comment: @LeeMosher : I updated the question.

Comment: And a subshift is what? Just a $T$-invariant subset?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes, it it a $T-$ invariant subset